# Open file in existing instance of Visual Studio 2017

Tags: windows-10, visual-studio-2017

I used to be able to open a file in an existing instance of VS - `devenv.exe` had a `/dde` switch for that.

But with VS2017 it opens the file in a new instance, not the one already running.

For example for json files:

- My registry has a key `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.json\OpenWithProgids` which contains a value `VisualStudio.json`.
- And there is a key `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\VisualStudio.json\shell\Open\Command` which contains the default value `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe" /dde`.

But that `/dde` is ignored.

Maybe all the betas and RCs corrupted something. My VS2017 is the latest updated version.

Does the `/dde` switch still work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay what was missing was these:

- `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\VisualStudio.json\shell\Open\ddeexec\` with a default value of `Open("%1")`.
- `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\VisualStudio.json\shell\Open\ddeexec\Application\` with a default value of `VisualStudio.15.0`
- `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\VisualStudio.json\shell\Open\ddeexec\Topic\` with a default value of `system`

All VS related files follow this pattern.

Comment: I'm having the same issue after upgrading to VS2017. Sadly this didn't work for me. I was trying to change the way LESS files opened. I tried updating `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\VisualStudio.less.14.0` and `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\VisualStudio.less.680b046f`, restarting Explorer and VS but no luck yet.

Comment: @BoffinbraiN Try using "15" instead of "14" (VS2017 instead of VS2015)

Comment: No luck, I'm afraid. I've even tried swapping over the full path of the program (`"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe" /dde`). It opens .asp and other files fine but not .less.

Comment: Also related, for other people's reference: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/41991/multiple-instances-of-vsopens-when-highlighting-an.html

Comment: @BoffinbraiN I had a path issue recently where I needed to use "c:\PROGRA~2\foo\bar" to get VS to recognise something. Worth a try?

Comment: It isn't an issue with opening the file. It opens the file fine. But it will always load up a brand new instance of VS to do it. Also not understanding why the exact same values are being used for other file extensions and they work fine.

Comment: I am having the same problem with VS2015 - it works fine on another machine but not on my PC. I have verified all reg keys have proper values.

Comment: Same problem here with VS2019 and *.trx files. All my registry keys seem to match the above.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with visual studio 2019 and windows 11.
I thought manipulating the registry was overkill, so I looked for a workaround.

Just create a .bat file with the following contents and select that .bat file from "Select Another Program".

```
start "" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\MSEnv\VSLauncher.exe" /edit %1
```

Comment: This actually works in VS2022.  It does indeed open the file within the existing instance of Visual Studio.  The accepted answer may have worked at one time, but doesn't work for me in VS2022 whereas this method does.

Comment: This seemed to have no effect for me. it still continued to open the file in a new instance of Visual Studio and not the previously opened instance associated with a solution