# How to re-use Visual Studio instance when viewing files?

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, file-association

I have a WPF application which has a "file view" feature which will launch an application based on an assumed file association. The files in question happen to be SpecFlow "feature" files (.feature). The application contains:

```
Process.Start(path);
```

... where `path` is full path to a .feature file.

I happen to have VS 2013, VS 2015, and VS 2017 installed on my development computer. When I first tested this feature, it would launch VS 2015 (not 2017!) to view the file; using the feature repeatedly would open files in the same 2015 instance (desirable behavior except that it is the wrong version of VS). I got it to use 2017 by using the Windows Control Panel Default Programs settings. After I did this, I found that it would launch a new VS 2017 instance for each file, or even repeated requests for the same file.

Ideally, I want to use the O/S built-in features/settings to open files in a single VS 2017 instance (assuming the presence of the correct file association). Is this a programming issue (use of Process.Start or an alternative) or an O/S configuration issue (file associations), and what would I (or a user of my application) need to do to achieve the behavior I am looking for (launch at most one new instance of VS2017 to view any number of supported files)?

Since VS will almost certainly be used as the file viewer, is there a VS integration feature (other than file associations) I could/should use for this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Open file in existing instance of Visual Studio 2017](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44130341/open-file-in-existing-instance-of-visual-studio-2017)

Comment: @dsdel close enough to call it a duplicate. It fixed my problem, raising only one new question: good or bad practice for my application to inspect the relevant registry settings and tweak them up as necessary?

Comment: @C Robinson In general you could provide an option for letting the user choose his desired default editor. If you have got a setup, you can simply add a setup option for adjusting the registry if not - perhaps a 'first start' setup would be nice? Either way, if you access the registry you need elevated permissions so the user would notice that your app is doing something and I would inform the user before about that requirement.